# Wifi disconnects after connecting a bluetooth device on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, bluetooth, ubuntu-18.04

I am using windows 8.1 along with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on a Lenovo G50-70. Whenever I connect my JBL Bluetooth (v4.2) earphone, my laptop's wifi disconnects after a few minutes. Please, someone, help me with this issue. I tried this command, but it didn't help:

```
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=1 bt_coex_active=0 power_save=0 auto_agg=0 swcrypto=1" | sudo tee /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf > /dev/null
```

Comment: The command may do something if that's the driver you're using, which is a driver for Intel WiFi only. If any other then it does nothing. And the `bt_coex_active` should be 1 (active) and why are you disabling 11n? There are specific situations where that is the recommendation but if the WiFi works fine, apart from the problem with the BT coexistence, there's no reason to do it. It seems you just copied this from somewhere without actually understanding what the command does (and maybe not even applicable if you have other than Intel WiFi hardware).

Comment: Could you please provide me a solution?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command, so we can know what the hardware you have. I may or may not be able to suggest a solution but others probably will. Without that information nobody can.

Comment: 02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:b723]
 Subsystem: Lenovo RTL8723BE PCIe Wireless Network Adapter [17aa:b736]
 Kernel driver in use: rtl8723be
 Kernel modules: rtl8723be
03:00.0 Display controller [0380]: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Sun LE [Radeon HD 8550M / R5 M230] [1002:666f] (rev ff)